# How can I extract and store and key/value returned by a server response in pharo/smalltalk

Tags: pharo

In my ZnClient request I get a response from the server which is a HTML format containing key and value that I would like to extract and store for later use. How do I do it in Pharo?

```html
<div id="login_block">
  <div class="text-center"><img src="/static/img/logo-mool2016.black.7272bc78ba54.png" width="223"  alt=LOGO" onclick="showChooseLogin();"></div>
    <h3 class="text-center">Connectez-vous pour accÃ©der Ã  <span class="product-name">Tool Platform</span></h3>
  <div id="login_choosen" class="login_block ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
   <form method="post" action="." id="login_form"><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='fLTzkLA7yhy7YKDvohM0PJstFJJCEk2JinfjOyzCe2NA495QKznLgO1wzi64P2S8' />
      <p><label for="id_email">EmailÂ :</label> <input class="login" id="id_email" maxlength="75" name="email" type="text" required /></p>
<p><label for="id_password">PasswordÂ :</label> <input class="login" id="id_password" name="password" type="password" required /></p>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-connect pull-right">Connexion</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the HTML that you have? Because I suppose that you can just load the XMLParser project from the catalog, use it to parse the HTML and create a dict (or association collection) from the DOM model

Comment: Dear @Uko I put the server response above in the question. Thank

Comment: There is also the PPXmlParser from PetitParser that you could try. Note however that you pasted some non ASCII characters which indicate that you have to pay attention to the encoding (usually UTF-8) too.

Comment: So which key-value pairs do you want to extract? Are these the input tags contents?

Comment: Dear @Uko I actually need to extract the 'csrfmiddlewaretoken' value contained in this server response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract this information using a HTML parser like [Soup](http://smalltalkhub.com/#!/~PharoExtras/Soup).

Here's a cut-down working example:

```
|content soup dict|

content := '
<div>
  <form method="post" action="." id="login_form">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="***special***" />
    <input class="login" id="id_email" name="email" type="text" required />
  </form>
</div>'.

dict := Dictionary new.
soup := Soup fromString: content.

(soup findAllTags: 'input') do: [ :each |
    dict at: (each attributeAt: 'name') put: (each attributeAt: 'value') ].
```

`dict` now contains the following:

```
'csrfmiddlewaretoken'->'***special***' 
'email'->nil
```

Comment: Dear @draegtun How can we transform the HTML into a string for using soup?

Comment: this works fine thank you for your help. problem now is that I have two output result with one being the csrfmiddlewaretoken. how can extract only its value

Comment: @ludo - `dict at: 'csrfmiddlewaretoken'.`

Answer (score 0):

You can load [`XMLParserHTML`](http://catalog.pharo.org/catalog/project/XMLParserHTML) and [`XPath`](http://catalog.pharo.org/catalog/project/XPath) from the Pharo Catalog. Then this should do the trick:

```
| xPath htmlDoc inputs input |

"match inputs with token value of the name attrite"
xPath   := '//input[@name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]' asXPath.

"parse your html"
htmlDoc := (XMLHTMLParser on: htmlString) parseDocument. 

"match all inputs with the token"
inputs  := xPath in: htmlDoc.

"assuming there is only 1 element like that"
input   := inputs first.

"get the value attribute from the element"
^ input attributeAt: 'value'.
```